# Lenovo V570 - WiFi disconnecting immediately (fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS image on a Lenovo V570 yesterday and the wifi disconnects immediately after attempting to connect (with correct WPA2 passkey). The wireless card in it is a Intel Centrino + WiMax 6150(?), the modem/router is 802.11b/g, and is verified to be working.

I'm VERY new to Linux/Ubuntu, so bear with me...

**A little more info:**
The rfkill list displays 3 separate devices, all unblocked except for the WiMax which displays

```
**WiMax**
Soft Blocked: Yes
Hard Blocked: No
```

Edit: After some assistance from Mr. Foerster, I gathered more information...

The output to the script can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23740244/

Thanks,
Stubbornmule

Comment: this post is very old(and very large to) but maybe help you :
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010968
Same card,same problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please (try to) associate your wireless adapter with an access point and then [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your non-standard issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ah @ppnman, I saw that thread and read through it. The original poster simply upgraded to 13.01 and solved their issue, but I would like to see if we can get this working on the latest version ;)

Comment: @ David, I will do my best!

Comment: Is anyone able to help? I installed this on my mother-in-laws laptop and am leaving post-holidays on Sunday and would really like to get this solved! XD